# I want to develop a CRUD interface for a website and I keep getting an error at the Edit method

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

The error I get is:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Albums_dbo.Artists_ArtistId". The conflict occurred in database "MusicStoreData", table "dbo.Artists", column 'ArtistId'

It occurs at the HttpPost Edit action.

All I want to do is to edit a specific album. For example: there is an album called AC/DC and I want to be able to edit the Genre, the Title, the Artist, etc.

I tried changing the view and to put a dropdownlist with the current Genres and Artist in the Db, but then I am getting a referential integrity error.

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);

        return View(album);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Album album)
{
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Album editAlbum = db.Albums.Find(album.AlbumId);
            //album.AlbumId = editAlbum.AlbumId;
            db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return (RedirectToAction("Index"));
        }

        return View(album);
}
```

This is the view:

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Album

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AlbumId)
        <legend>Album</legend>

        <div>
            Genre<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Genre.Name)
        </div>
        <div>
            Artist<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Artist.Name)
        </div>
        <div>
            Title<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)
        </div>
        <div>
            Price<br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price)
        </div>
        <div>
            Description<br />
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Genre.Description)
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>@Html.ActionLink("Return to List", "Index")</div>
```

And these are the model classes:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    }

    public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artist
    {
        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the DbContext:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know that I am missing something, but I really can't put my finger on it. I would be glad if there is someone willing to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Try to figure out what exact SQL statement is generated by EF. Seems like it's trying to add AC/DC again - let there be rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this two ways:

**1. Easy Way and Incomplete way - just to get rid of that error**

Just add:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ArtistId)
```

To your form. Your requests are stateless, so the server is just being sent what is contained in your form. This however would keep you from being able to change your artist with one of your textboxes (but that also won't work, which I'll touch in the second option).

**2. Slightly Better Way**

Right now, you are posting data to your controller that doesn't match your model. Your controller is expecting an `Album` type object and you're posting things like `Genre.Name`, which `Album` does not have have. As a result, your controller will default to `0` for your foreign keys for these objects (that's the problem you're facing now). I would recommend making a new class called `AlbumEditViewModel` that contains the text fields for `GenreName` and `ArtistName` (you probably want to remove `Genre.Description` from this view as I don't think you want to edit it). In your get method for this view, hydrate the ViewModel with the appropriate values for the given album, and then send that to the view. On your post method, you'll get the `Album` model from the database based on the `Album.AlbumId` and also get the  Ids for `Genre` and `Artist` and then set the Ids of your `Album` model before saving `Album`.

**Other Recommendations**

I would probably change this to be dropdowns instead of textbox as right now it will require exact matches to get the artist ID. Alternatively, you could keep it as textboxes and have your controller check if an artist exists with such a name and if it doesn't, create a new artist in the database with that name before assigning the ID.

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: So I should create a ViewModel like this: 
 public string GenreName { get; set; }
  public string ArtistName { get; set; }
And how should I populate them in my get method?

Comment: Yes, and also include a property for AlbumID (and other properties you want to show). In your GET method, get the Album from the database like you do and the just create a new instance of your ViewModel and copy the properties over manually. There are libraries to do this automatically (AutoMapper) and you might want to consider learning about them. Very useful and allow you to write much more maintainable code.